# Error decoding JSON data - Joomla 3.6.5

Tags: php, json, joomla

Yesterday I started working with Joomla CMS. when I wanted to change the size of social icons I encountered an error when I made the refresh page.

```
Error displaying the error page: Error decoding JSON data: Syntax error: Error decoding JSON data: Syntax error
```

To diagnose the problem I downloaded plugin json-db-check.php and when I used it as a result received:

```
Checking table: a_assets, column rules

Checking table: a_banners, column params

Checking table: a_categories, column params

Checking table: a_contact_details, column params

Checking table: a_content, column attribs

Checking table: a_content_types, column rules

Checking table: a_extensions, column params

Checking table: a_finder_filters, column params

Checking table: a_menu, column params

Checking table: a_modules, column params

Checking table: a_newsfeeds, column params

Checking table: a_nextend2_smartslider3_generators, column params

Checking table: a_nextend2_smartslider3_sliders, column params

Checking table: a_nextend2_smartslider3_slides, column params

Checking table: a_tags, column params

Checking table: a_template_styles, column params

Row 10 is not valid JSON. Error: (Syntax error)
Content: #sp-bottom2 .icon-facebook:before, #sp-bottom2 .icon-twitter:before { font-size:40px !important; }
Checking table: a_users, column params

Checking table: a_viewlevels, column rules

Checking table: bak_a_assets, column rules

Checking table: bak_a_banners, column params

Checking table: bak_a_categories, column params

Checking table: bak_a_contact_details, column params

Checking table: bak_a_content, column attribs

Checking table: bak_a_content_types, column rules

Checking table: bak_a_extensions, column params

Checking table: bak_a_finder_filters, column params

Checking table: bak_a_menu, column params

Checking table: bak_a_modules, column params

Checking table: bak_a_newsfeeds, column params

Checking table: bak_a_tags, column params

Checking table: bak_a_template_styles, column params

Checking table: bak_a_users, column params

Checking table: bak_a_viewlevels, column rules

Finished checking invalid parameters
```

Where I can deleted this style?

```
Checking table: a_template_styles, column params

Row 10 is not valid JSON. Error: (Syntax error)
Content: #sp-bottom2 .icon-facebook:before, #sp-bottom2 .icon-twitter:before { font-size:40px !important; }
```

In table `a_template_styles` I can't find #sp-bottom where should it look?
What should I do??

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

if you need a quick fix to get back in, download the 3.6.2 full package, unzip and upload contents to server.

Comment: I want to remove my entry styles css from a_template_styles but I'dont know how .. Because they do not know where my entry is stored in JSON file ...